# Is it possible to print matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, printing, formatting, display

I have this very simple function which takes an integer as input, generates two random matrices and multiplies them before printing the time it takes.

```
function [] = mymatrix(n)
mat1 = randi([0 100], n, n);
mat2 = randi([0 100], n, n);
tic
result = mymult(mat1, mat2);
disp("First matrix:")
disp(mat1) 
disp("Second matrix:")
disp(mat2)
disp("Multiplied:")
disp(result);
toc
end
```

The program works, and I get this output:

```
>> mymatrix(2)
Elapsed time is 0.000614 seconds.
First matrix:
    34    10
    77    87

Second matrix:
    11    31
    30    81

Multiplied:
         674        1864
        3457        9434

Elapsed time is 0.002148 seconds.
```

But I was wondering if it is possible to write the `display` lines more compact?

Something like this: `fprintf("Calculated: \r", X)` but for matrices? Because when I try to write `fprintf("First matrix: " + mat1)`, like so:

```
function [] = mymatrix(n)
mat1 = randi([0 100], n, n);
mat2 = randi([0 100], n, n);
tic
result = mymult(mat1, mat2);
fprintf("First matrix: " + mat1)
%disp(mat1) 
disp("Second matrix:")
disp(mat2)
disp("Multiplied:")
disp(result);
toc
end
```

I get an error:

```
>> mymatrix(2)
Error using fprintf
Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.
```

Comment: you don't want to print in a file `fprintf`, but in a string `sprintf`

Comment: I still get an error saying it's `Invalid format`

Comment: I might have used the wrong wording when writing the title for my question. The output is correct, it was just I who wanted to compress the code so that I don't have 6 display lines.

Comment: No, the question is clear. But "I still get an error" is unclear, show us the code that causes error. Also check docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you can combine variables' values into strings/chars using `sprintf` or `fprintf`, which allow format specifiers for how the variable should be formatted in the string. However, you will have issues trying to use `printf` commands for matrix inputs, because they try to expand inputs of different sizes.

Example for `n=2`

```
>> fprintf( 'First matrix: \n%d', mat1 )
First matrix: 
82First matrix: 
80First matrix: 
65First matrix: 
38
```

The easiest one-liner in this case is probably to just abuse `cellfun` a bit instead, which will loop over its inputs and call any function, in this case `disp`:

```
cellfun( @disp, {'First matrix:', mat1, 'Second matrix:', mat2, 'Multiplied:', result} );
```

This gives you exactly the same output as before, because it's doing literally the same thing (calling `disp` on your 6 inputs).

```
First matrix:
    88    62
    55    59
Second matrix:
    20    47
    30    23
Multiplied:
        3620        5562
        2870        3942
```

I'm not sure this is any better than the original 6-line option, sure it's now a one liner but it's also arguably reduced your code readability.